# Text for chat interface overflowing - CSS

Tags: html, css

I searched everywhere, but almost no-one seems to take this into account. I have a chat interface, its a div element, within it a ul, then inside that are li which contains p elements.

html:

```css
.chatRight {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  max-width: 50%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: table;
}
.chatLeft {
  background-color: aqua;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  max-width: 60%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.chatBoxRight {
  text-align: right;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.chatBoxLeft {
  text-align: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
#chatList {
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  list-style-type: none;
  max-width: calc(100% - 80px);
}
#chatList li {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatContainer">
  <ul id="chatList">
    <li class="chatBoxLeft">
      <p class="chatLeft">Hello there!</p>
    </li>
    <li class="chatBoxRight">
      <p class="chatRight">Good day</p>
    </li>
    <li class="chatBoxLeft">
      <p class="chatLeft">How do you do?</p>
    </li>
    <li class="chatBoxRight">
      <p class="chatRight">hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    </li>
    <li class="chatBoxRight">
      <p class="chatRight">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now the problem is the overflowing, everything seems nice and blobby, except for aaa..., cause it makes the rounded p overflow. It's not just this, but the max-width also does not seem to be working in cases.

(For the sake of demonstration I just added the display:table to the right-box p elements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add `word-break: break-all;` to change when line breaks

https://jsfiddle.net/nqp685h1/

Answer (score 1):

Remove `display: table;` from `.chatRight`, or use `word-break: break-all;` instead of `word-wrap: break-word;`

```css
.chatRight {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  max-width: 50%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.chatLeft {
  background-color: aqua;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  max-width: 60%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.chatBoxRight {
  text-align: right;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.chatBoxLeft {
  text-align: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
#chatList {
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  list-style-type: none;
  max-width: calc(100% - 80px);
}
#chatList li {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatContainer">
  <ul id="chatList">
    <li class="chatBoxLeft">
      <p class="chatLeft">Hello there!</p>
    </li>
    <li class="chatBoxRight">
      <p class="chatRight">Good day</p>
    </li>
    <li class="chatBoxLeft">
      <p class="chatLeft">How do you do?</p>
    </li>
    <li class="chatBoxRight">
      <p class="chatRight">hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    </li>
    <li class="chatBoxRight">
      <p class="chatRight">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```